# AttributeError: 'ArtistList' object has no attribute 'pop'

Tags: python, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, reinforcement-learning, attributeerror

```
>>> import jsbgym
>>> import gymnasium as gym
>>> env = gym.make("JSBSim-HeadingControlTask-Cessna172P-Shaping.STANDARD", render_mode="human")
>>> env.reset()


     JSBSim Flight Dynamics Model v1.1.13 [GitHub build 986/commit a09715f01b9e568ce75ca2635ba0a78ce57f7cdd] Dec  3 2022 12:36:17
            [JSBSim-ML v2.0]

JSBSim startup beginning ...

(array([ 5.00000000e+03,  1.21430643e-17,  1.50920942e-16,  2.02536000e+02,
        4.44089210e-15, -5.32907052e-15,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,
        0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,
        0.00000000e+00, -3.72529030e-09,  1.25629209e-15,  0.00000000e+00,
        2.99000000e+02]), {})
>>> env.render()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\noahs\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\gymnasium\wrappers\order_enforcing.py", line 52, in render
    return self.env.render(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\noahs\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\gymnasium\wrappers\env_checker.py", line 53, in render
    return env_render_passive_checker(self.env, *args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\noahs\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\gymnasium\utils\passive_env_checker.py", line 384, in env_render_passive_checker
    result = env.render()
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\noahs\Coding\AI\RL\JSBGym\jsbgym\environment.py", line 161, in render
    self.figure_visualiser.plot(self.sim)
  File "C:\Users\noahs\Coding\AI\RL\JSBGym\jsbgym\visualiser.py", line 64, in plot
    data = subplot.lines.pop()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'ArtistList' object has no attribute 'pop'
```

I tried rendering this environment with human https://github.com/sryu1/jsbgym
but I keep getting this error. I understand that I can't use pop() with ArtistList but I don't know what is using ArtistList, could someone check my repo and see if there's any solution to that? Thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just replace `lines.pop(0)` with `lines[0].remove()` or

```
for line in lines:
    line.remove()
```

Comment: I swear I tried that last time but it didn't work... Well, now it worked, thank you!

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem when using colour-science. Apparently, matplotlib 3.7.x does not have the lines.pop(0) function implemented. For me, it worked when downgrading back to matplotlib 3.6.3. I hope that works for you too.

Comment: Yeah, I just noticed yesterday as well, would it be a good idea to raise an issue report?